# How do I remove a book from my Sony Reader?

Tags: ebook-readers, sony-prs-t1

I have lots of space left on my Sony Reader (a PRS-T1), but I also have a few books on there that I don't want to read again (or at all). I am trying to figure out how to remove them from the reader using the software that came with it, but I seem to be missing some vital bit of explanation, because I can't seem to take books off of the reader.

Some of the books I want to remove are expired library loans, and some are actual books I have bought and paid for, if that makes any difference. Ideally, I'd like a way to remove multiple titles at once, but if not, one at a time will work too.

Comment: I don't have enough rep yet to add new tags - can someone create a sony-prs-t1 tag (or whatever would be appropriate) for me?

Comment: Tag has been added. Welcome to Ebooks SE.

Comment: Ashley, if this isn't answered by the time I get home (about 4 hours), I'll let you know. I don't have the software installed on my work laptop, but I do have it at home. I should note that if you plug your reader into your laptop/PC, you can actually browse to the device like it is a usb drive. You can find the list of books under one of the folders (can't remember at the moment) and just delete it. I often do this when I'm not on my personal laptop.

Comment: It's `database/media/books` on PRS-650.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove files from the PRS-T1 you can connect the reader via its USB cable to a computer and have the internal memory available as a USB drive. The TRS-1 shows itself as two USB devices, one named SETTINGS, the other READER.
The books are normally under READER/BOOKS.

You can just search for, and delete the books with your OS' file browser.

The device will rebuild the database of available books after disconnecting it from the computer.
**Make sure to properly remove the device, do not just unplug it.**

Answer (score 3):

On Sony PRS-650 when you read a book, press the Menu button then there is a Delete Book menu entry.

[PRS-T1 manual](http://pdf.crse.com/manuals/4288613111/eng/contents/06/01/01/01.html) says the following:

> **Deleting a Single Item**
>
> You can delete individual items. The following instructions use the
>   [Books] application as an example; this feature is also available in
>   other applications.
>
> 1. Press the  (Home) button  tap [Books].
> 2. Tap and hold an item. The option items appear.
> 3. Tap [Delete].
> 4. Tap [Yes] when prompted. The item is deleted from the Reader.

There is also a way to for [deleting multiple items at once](http://pdf.crse.com/manuals/4288613111/eng/contents/06/01/02/02.html).

Comment: I was sort of hoping there would be a way to do this without doing it on the reader itself, as I find accomplishing anything but reading on it takes a long time, as things seem to happen slowly (like going through pages of books to find the one I want).

Comment: @AshleyNunn: Then you should go with Jason's answer/comment.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a response for future people like me
I've got a Sony PRS-T2, accessed on the laptop with Adobe Reader for PC.

I've found that adding or deleting books to the ereader using the computer's File Explorer (as suggested by a previous commenter) does NOT work.
To add books, you have to use the related program (Reader for PC) to import books onto the device.
And deleting books via the file explorer seems to do nothing at all.

I couldn't find a way to delete things from the eReader itself using the program.
For my eReader, the only way to delete things that I have found is (as described by the other commenter) to go onto the eReader itself (not the computer), go to the bookshelves, press and hold on the relevant book

- this comes up with a menu, one of the options is delete.

This is a one at a time thing, I can't see a mass delete method. This is probably deliberate to prevent accidental disaster.