# Why can't I remove books from my device?

Tags: calibre, sony-prs-t1

I used to be able to remove books from my Sony PRS-T1 reader using Calibre (either one by one or en masse). I am running a fully updated version of Windows 7, and I have the latest version of Calibre (1.20), and tried today to remove some books (both one at a time, and multiples at a time), and I keep getting the following error when I try:

> calibre, version 1.19.0 ERROR: Error: Error communicating with device
>
> [Error 5] Access is denied: u'M:\Sony_Reader\media\books\The
>   Zombie Survival Guide_ Complete Prot - Max Brooks.epub'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "site-packages\calibre\gui2\device.py", line 85, in run   File
>   "site-packages\calibre\gui2\device.py", line 596, in _delete_books
>   File "site-packages\calibre\devices\usbms\driver.py", line 345, in
>   delete_books WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied:
>   u'M:\Sony_Reader\media\books\The Zombie Survival Guide_ Complete
>   Prot - Max Brooks.epub'

While the filename listed will change (depending on the book I am trying to delete), the message is the same - I can't delete ebooks from my device.

Is there anything I can do to solve this error?

Comment: Can you delete the file manually, i.e. in the explorer without using Calibre?

Comment: I can delete it on the device manually but I have not tried using the file Explorer to do so.

Comment: See suggestion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12058/ebooks)

Comment: I think you need to provide more **relevant** information: What is your version of Calibre. Guessing have Windows (from path in the error message, which version?

Comment: @ReginaT. I added those details in :)

Comment: Did you update to the current calibre version (1.47)? Have you tried uninstalling and installing again calibre?

Comment: @Daniel yes to both of those things.

Answer (score 4):

It might be that the TRS-1 plugin for Calibre is broken, or that Calibre deletion is broken in the version you have. I would try to delete files outside of Calibre using the steps [here](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/a/582/60), and if that works blame things on Calibre, file a bug-report and wait for the next version.

Answer (score 2):

This is a security feature in windows that is intended to prevent malicious programs from removing content from your devices with out your permission.  Depending on how the program is implemented you may be able to delete files if you start Calibre with administrator privileges.  Simply right click the shortcut and choose "Run as administrator."

Comment: I am not convinced that is the case, as I used to be able to do it with no issues, and nothing has changed about my Windows install since then.

Comment: @AshleyNunn - You have not installed the latest security patches?  Mine broke about 6 weeks ago after one.  If I run in admin mode then it works.  I do not know about calibre but I noticed it with an app for managing my mobile phone.

Comment: @AshleyNunn: I have seen similar issues where a windows update was applied and it affected a program or two that used to run without admin privs, but then required me to run it as admin.

Comment: I tried running it as an administrator, and the same thing happened. :(